# 403 response code with http but not with https on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, https, http-status-code-403

I got an issue. I got a WordPress website and I got a 403 HTTP response code when I try to access it with HTTP, but it works well with https.
I already thought that is was a redirection problem so I added this code to my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

do you have an idea, please ... I really don't understand where it can come from ...

Thank you

PS :

My complete .htaccess :

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Update default WordPress htaccess

Comment: _Aside:_ You should be modifying the code inside the `# BEGIN WordPress` code block. Any custom redirects should be _before_ this.

Comment: How long has this been happening? Do you have access to the server config?

Answer (score 0):

Update this code in your htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Try this let me know i think its work for you

Comment: No it's not working ...
Here is my website url if you wanna look at it : 
working : https://www.geneweb.eu
not working : http://www.geneweb.eu

(how are you formating code in stack overflow's post ? so i can send you my complete .htaccess)

Comment: I added to my post my complete .htaccess